# What is a context.parent value inside a TestActorRef?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-testkit

I have a small test in Scala/Akka

```
"test test" in {

  val actor = TestActorRef(new Actor {
    override def receive: Receive = {
      case _ =>
        println("Inside actor " + context.parent)
        context.parent ! 42
    }
  })

  println("Self " + self)

  actor ! "Hello"

  expectMsg(42)
}
```

The output it produces is

```
Self Actor[akka://testSystem/system/testActor1#-1014751973]
Inside actor Actor[akka://testSystem/user]
(...)
assertion failed: timeout (3 seconds) during expectMsg while waiting for 42
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: timeout (3 seconds) during expectMsg while waiting for 42
```

Why is `context.parent` inside the actor not the real parent which I would expect to be the `testActor1` as we see in the logs? (this is the actor I expect to be a parent as it created the subject).

If that state of matter expected - if so, why? I don't see any benefit of such approach.

Comment: Your actor is a top level actor, therefore the parent is the root guardian which is exactly what is printed out (`akka://testSystem/user`).  Not sure what you are expecting here.

Comment: Also, there is a version of the `apply` method on the `TestActorRef` companion that takes an explicit supervisor.  In lieu of this the code uses the root guardian which is what you are seeing.

Comment: "Your actor is a top level actor" - well, not really, entire test has it "self" which is "testActor1" (the one which is a `sender` inside my `actor`). I create my actor inside this actor, then I expect a parent-child relation

Comment: See my answer below.  If you look at the source for `TestActorRef` you will see that when no explicit supervisor is supplied that it always defaults to the root guardian.

Comment: I understand, my question is rather - why is this that way, instead of using this 'testActor1' which would make much more sense IMO

Comment: You keep referring to `testActor1` but I don't see that anywhere in your code sample.  Can you share more of the code so I can see that?

Comment: Its in the output `Self Actor[akka://testSystem/system/testActor1#-1014751973]` - and its basically the `self` of a test case

Comment: Your test itself is not an actor just because it mixes in `ImplicitSender`.  That trait just gives you an implicit `ActorRef` (`self`) that is around to act as the `sender` when performing a tell (`!`) on your test actor ref

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibilities for what this can be.  If you call one of the `apply` methods on the `TestActorRef` companion that does not accept an explicit supervisor `ActorRef` then the parent will be the root guardian.  If you do call the one that takes an explicit supervisor then the parent will be that `ActorRef` that you supply.